# Adding dynamic UI to my program (Shiny R)

Tags: r, shiny

I have another problem with my program. I made small program, you upload file, set some parameters like separator, header etc and look at table to check, all parameters are alright. Then you can create own table with selected columns or histogram.

This is code of program.

```
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("StatMaciej - Prototyp numer 9"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

    #start of dynamic ui
    #There will be menu called "plik_regulacja" 
h4("Na początek"),
      fileInput("file", label = h5("Wgraj Plik")),
      h4("Ustaw odpowiednie parametry (patrz na tabele 'dane' by sprawdzić czy wszystko jest cacy)"),
      checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Pierwszy wers to etykiety', value = FALSE),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Co jest separatorem', choices = c("Przecinek"=',',"Średnik"=';',"Tabulator"='\t', "Spacja"=''), selected = ','),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'dec', label = 'Co jest separatorem dziesiętnym', choices = c("Przecinek"=',',"Kropka"='.'), selected = ','),
    #There will be menu called "wlasna_tabela"    
      h4("Utwórz tabele z wybranych kolumn"),
      checkboxGroupInput("choices1", label = h5("Wybierz Kolumny"), choices = NULL),
    #There will be menu called "histogram"    
h4("Interfejs tworzenia histogramu"),
        selectInput("combobox", label = h5("Wybierz kolumne"),  choices = NULL),

        sliderInput("slider1", label = h5("Częstotliwość zakresów"), min = 1, max = 100, value = 20),
h5("wybierz kolor histogramu"),     
        colourInput("kolor", NULL, "blue", showColour = "background"),
h5("wybierz kolor konturu"),            
        colourInput("kontur", NULL, "black", palette = "limited", showColour = "background"),
        textInput("etykietax", label = h5("Nazwa etykiety x"), value = "przedziały"),
        textInput("etykietay", label = h5("Nazwa etykiety y"), value = "występowanie w przedziałach"),
    radioButtons("radio", label = h5("Usunąc w tytule 'Histogram kolumny'?"),
    choices = list("Nie" = "Histogram kolumny", "Tak" = " "), 
    selected = "Nie")
# End of dynamic UI



    ),

    mainPanel(
       uiOutput("tb")
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session){

  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    dataSet <- read.csv(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, dec = input$dec )

    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "choices1", choices = colnames(dataSet))
      # this line updates selection in combobox 
    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox", choices = colnames(dataSet))

    dataSet
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()    
  })

  output$table2 <- renderTable({


    if(is.null(data()) || is.null(input$choices1)){return ()}
    data()[input$choices1]    
  })

# there is part of file where i make histogram
  output$wykres <- renderPlot({
    x    <- data()[, input$combobox] 

    if (!is.numeric(x)) {
      createAlert(session, "alarm", alertId = "niebezpieczenstwo", 
                  title = "Histogram nie może zostać stworzony: ",
                  content = "Dane podanej kolumny muszą być wartościami liczbowymi. Jeśli podane dane są wartościami liczbowymi, upewnij się że ustawiłeś prawidłowy separator dziesiętny", 
                  style = "danger", dismiss = TRUE, append = TRUE)
    }
    if (is.numeric(x)) {
      closeAlert(session, "niebezpieczenstwo")
    }

    req(is.numeric(x))

    hist(x , col = input$kolor, border = input$kontur, main = paste(input$radio , input$combobox), xlab = input$etykietax, ylab = input$etykietay, breaks = input$slider1)
  })



  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data()))
      h5("Wgraj Plik jeśli chcesz cokolwiek zrobić.")
    else
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("dane", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("wybrane kolumny", tableOutput("table2")), tabPanel("Histogram", 
                           bsAlert("alarm"),
                           plotOutput("wykres")))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This program is working, but there is other problem, as you see menu with options is too big. So i decided to improve it using information from this page (http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/dynamic-ui.html) and make dynamic ui where there are grouped options (1st group for upload and choosing basic parameters, 2nd group to select columns to custom table option, and 3th group for histogram options).

so this is code of "Improved" program

```
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("StatMaciej - Prototyp numer 11"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

selectInput("input_type", "Co chesz zrobic",
        c("plik_regulacja", "wlasna_tabela", "histogram")
        ),

              uiOutput("ui")



    ),

    mainPanel(
       uiOutput("tb")
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session){

output$ui <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(input$input_type))
      return()


    switch(input$input_type,
      "plik_regulacja" = fileInput("file", label = h5("Wgraj Plik")),
      h4("Ustaw odpowiednie parametry (patrz na tabele 'dane' by sprawdzić czy wszystko jest cacy)"),
      checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Pierwszy wers to etykiety', value = FALSE),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Co jest separatorem', choices = c("Przecinek"=',',"Średnik"=';',"Tabulator"='\t', "Spacja"=''), selected = ','),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'dec', label = 'Co jest separatorem dziesiętnym', choices = c("Przecinek"=',',"Kropka"='.'), selected = ','),
      "wlasna_tabela" = checkboxGroupInput("choices1", label = h5("Wybierz Kolumny"), choices = NULL),
      "histogram" = selectInput("combobox", label = h5("Wybierz kolumne"),  choices = NULL),

        sliderInput("slider1", label = h5("Częstotliwość zakresów"), min = 1, max = 100, value = 20),
h5("wybierz kolor histogramu"),     
        colourInput("kolor", NULL, "blue", showColour = "background"),
h5("wybierz kolor konturu"),            
        colourInput("kontur", NULL, "black", palette = "limited", showColour = "background"),
        textInput("etykietax", label = h5("Nazwa etykiety x"), value = "przedziały"),
        textInput("etykietay", label = h5("Nazwa etykiety y"), value = "występowanie w przedziałach"),
    radioButtons("radio", label = h5("Usunąc w tytule 'Histogram kolumny'?"),
    choices = list("Nie" = "Histogram kolumny", "Tak" = " "), 
    selected = "Nie")
    )
  })


  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    dataSet <- read.csv(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, dec = input$dec )

    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "choices1", choices = colnames(dataSet))
      # this line updates selection in combobox 
    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox", choices = colnames(dataSet))

    dataSet
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()    
  })

  output$table2 <- renderTable({


    if(is.null(data()) || is.null(input$choices1)){return ()}
    data()[input$choices1]    
  })

# there is part of file where i make histogram
  output$wykres <- renderPlot({
    x    <- data()[, input$combobox] 

    if (!is.numeric(x)) {
      createAlert(session, "alarm", alertId = "niebezpieczenstwo", 
                  title = "Histogram nie może zostać stworzony: ",
                  content = "Dane podanej kolumny muszą być wartościami liczbowymi. Jeśli podane dane są wartościami liczbowymi, upewnij się że ustawiłeś prawidłowy separator dziesiętny", 
                  style = "danger", dismiss = TRUE, append = TRUE)
    }
    if (is.numeric(x)) {
      closeAlert(session, "niebezpieczenstwo")
    }

    req(is.numeric(x))

    hist(x , col = input$kolor, border = input$kontur, main = paste(input$radio , input$combobox), xlab = input$etykietax, ylab = input$etykietay, breaks = input$slider1)
  })



  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data()))
      h5("Wgraj Plik jeśli chcesz cokolwiek zrobić.")
    else
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("dane", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("wybrane kolumny", tableOutput("table2")), tabPanel("Histogram", 
                           bsAlert("alarm"),
                           plotOutput("wykres")))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

but when i want to open program and do something, no matter what, it displays this error.
[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9CCb.png)

What i made wrong, and how can i fix it.

I give fragments where i made changes to make things easier

ui part

```
selectInput("input_type", "Co chesz zrobic",
    c("plik_regulacja", "wlasna_tabela", "histogram")
    ),

          uiOutput("ui")
```

Server part

```
output$ui <- renderUI({
        if (is.null(input$input_type))
          return()


        switch(input$input_type,
          "plik_regulacja" = fileInput("file", label = h5("Wgraj Plik")),
          h4("Ustaw odpowiednie parametry (patrz na tabele 'dane' by sprawdzić czy wszystko jest cacy)"),
          checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Pierwszy wers to etykiety', value = FALSE),
          radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Co jest separatorem', choices = c("Przecinek"=',',"Średnik"=';',"Tabulator"='\t', "Spacja"=''), selected = ','),
          radioButtons(inputId = 'dec', label = 'Co jest separatorem dziesiętnym', choices = c("Przecinek"=',',"Kropka"='.'), selected = ','),
          "wlasna_tabela" = checkboxGroupInput("choices1", label = h5("Wybierz Kolumny"), choices = NULL),
          "histogram" = selectInput("combobox", label = h5("Wybierz kolumne"),  choices = NULL),

            sliderInput("slider1", label = h5("Częstotliwość zakresów"), min = 1, max = 100, value = 20),
    h5("wybierz kolor histogramu"),     
            colourInput("kolor", NULL, "blue", showColour = "background"),
    h5("wybierz kolor konturu"),            
            colourInput("kontur", NULL, "black", palette = "limited", showColour = "background"),
            textInput("etykietax", label = h5("Nazwa etykiety x"), value = "przedziały"),
            textInput("etykietay", label = h5("Nazwa etykiety y"), value = "występowanie w przedziałach"),
        radioButtons("radio", label = h5("Usunąc w tytule 'Histogram kolumny'?"),
        choices = list("Nie" = "Histogram kolumny", "Tak" = " "), 
        selected = "Nie")
```

Comment: The problem is with `switch` which should only have one argument (other than the expression) that are not in the form of `a=b`. This one argument will be the default value.

Comment: @warmoverflow well if switch is a problem... maybe there is good library with better version of switch command what will help me solve this problem? But i dont know how named is this library or even is it exists.